# Create spark dataframe from JSON file

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have below JSON file:

```
{
     "docID":"dfter-yutr"
     "user" : [ [ "2111", "OLIVIA", "37" ]
              , [ "2112", "AVA", "47" ]
              , [ "2113", "ISABELLA", "55" ]
}
```

I need to read 'user' node from this file into a spark data frame.

I have created a schema object as
`Schema = ["id","Name", "Age"]`

I'm trying to use below code:
`df = spark.createDataFrame(<Need to pass Data here>, schema=schema)`

Can someone help me in finding a right way to pass the data to CreateDataFrame method. My Json file has 100,000 records what is the best optimized approach to create a data frame from this.

Comment: What's your file format? Is it [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org/)? The easiest way to load JSON data is with JSON lines. Check [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) out. If you are not using JSON lines it gets trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



input_file = "../data/jsonUserSOHelp.json"
df0 = sqlContext.read \
    .option("multiLine", True)\
    .json(input_file)
# .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
print("df0")
df0.show(n=100, truncate=False)
schema = ["id","Name", "Age"]

df0_explode = df0.withColumn("exploded_user", F.explode(F.col("user")))
df_req = df0_explode.select(F.col("exploded_user").getItem(0).alias(schema[0]), F.col("exploded_user").getItem(1).alias(schema[1]), F.col("exploded_user").getItem(2).alias(schema[2]))
print("df_req")
df_req.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output  :

```
df0
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|docID     |user                                                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|dfter-yutr|[[2111, OLIVIA, 37], [2112, AVA, 47], [2113, ISABELLA, 55]]|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+

df_req
+----+--------+---+
|id  |Name    |Age|
+----+--------+---+
|2111|OLIVIA  |37 |
|2112|AVA     |47 |
|2113|ISABELLA|55 |
+----+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

pyspark is able to read json files into dataframes using spark.read.json(). However, the input json file needs to either be in JSON lines format:

```
{"id": "2111", "name": "OLIVIA", "age": "37"}
{"id": "2112", "name": "AVA", "age": "47"}
```

or as a multiline JSON using the `option('multiline', True)`:

```
[
{"id": "2111", "name": "OLIVIA", "age": "37"},
{"id": "2112", "name": "AVA", "age": "47"}
]
```

Using your current json format I'd rather use the json library to grab the user list and convert that to a list of tuples:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as readfile:
    jsondata = json.load(readfile)
    users = jsondata['user']

data = [tuple(i) for i in users]
schema = ['id', 'name', 'age']

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df2.show()
```

The best approach however would be to format the JSON file as JSON lines with each line representing a record with the keys in the record/object representing column names. spark.read.json() is able to infer schema by default.